# Slightly increasing complexity of function increases calculation time by magnitudes

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning

I am trying to calculate an impedance value from voltage and current functions. The calculation method is based on how an actual measurement device performs it.

I have two different current function, where one is slightly more complex.

```
iBV[t_, freq_] = 
  i0*(-Exp[(alpha - 1)*bvVor*(U[t, freq] - E0)] + 
  Exp[alpha*bvVor*(U[t, freq] - E0)]) + Cdl*DU[t, freq];
i[t_, freq_] = iBV[t, freq]*iLimit/(Abs[iBV[t, freq]] + iLimit);
```

If i use `iBV` directly, the calculations finish very rapidly. When I however use `i` I am still waiting for the results after half an hour and I don't understand why. Granted, it has to calculate `iBV` twice for each round but shouldn't that lead to twice the time and not 1000 times?

As you'll see I need to integrate. Is maybe the complexity of performing the integration much more complicated in the latter case for some reason?

The rest of the computation is as follows:

```
ClearAll[t, freq, U0, Harmonic, bvVor, i0, alpha, E0, T, z, cBulk, 
  Cdl, iLimit];
ClearAll[U, DU, iVoigt, i, iL, Rea, Ima, tmax, ReZ, ImZ, Impe];

(* Current parameters *)
i0 = 0.0001; alpha = 0.5; E0 = 0; T = 293; z = 1; cBulk = 25; Cdl = \
0.000001; iLimit = 0.0005;

(* Voltage parameters and Misc *)
U0 = 0.1;
Harmonic = 0;
bvVor = z*96485/8.314/T;

(* Voltage Functions *)
U[t_, freq_] = U0*Sin[2*\[Pi]*freq*t];
DU[t_, freq_] = 2*freq*\[Pi]*U0*Cos[2*freq*\[Pi]*t];
(*iVoigt[t_,freq_]=Cdl*DU[t,freq]+U[t,freq]/100;*)

(* Current Function *)
iBV[t_, freq_] = 
  i0*(-Exp[(alpha - 1)*bvVor*(U[t, freq] - E0)] + 
      Exp[alpha*bvVor*(U[t, freq] - E0)]) + Cdl*DU[t, freq];
i[t_, freq_] = iBV[t, freq]*iLimit/(Abs[iBV[t, freq]] + iLimit);

(* Functions to calculate the real and imaginary part of the current \
by integration *)
ReaF[t_, freq_] = i[t, freq]*Sin[(Harmonic + 1)*2*\[Pi]*freq*t];
ImaF[t_, freq_] = i[t, freq]*Cos[(Harmonic + 1)*2*\[Pi]*freq*t];

(* Integration bound, 1 period *)
tmax[freq_] = 2/freq;

(* Real and Imaginary part of the current *)
ReI[freq_] = 2/tmax[freq]*Integrate[ReaF[t, freq], {t, 0, tmax[freq]}];
ImI[freq_] = 2/tmax[freq]*Integrate[ImaF[t, freq], {t, 0, tmax[freq]}];

(* The Impedance *)
Impe[freq_] = U0/(ReI[freq] + I*ImI[freq]);

(* Calculation of results *)
Freqs = 10^Range[-2,5,0.1];
Results = Impe[Freqs];

(* Output *)
Res = Re[Results];
Ims = Im[Results];
marker = Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}];
ListPlot[Transpose[{Res, -Ims}], {Joined -> True, 
  PlotMarkers -> {marker, .03}, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Thick}}]
TraditionalForm[TableForm[Transpose[{Freqs, Res, Ims}]]]
```

If you want to test the difference, just rename `i[t_, freq_]` to something, and rename `iBV[t_, freq_]` to `i[t_, freq_]`.

I also tried rewriting the whole stuff in Function/Module nomenclature, getting rid of doubled calculations in the process, but that just made everything slower (i guess due to overhead<->actual evaluation time bias).

**Edit**

I tried to do some benchmarks:

```
Timing[Do[iBV[0.1, 100], {10000}]]
Timing[Do[i[0.1, 110], {10000}]]
```

This does indeed report what I thought: `{0.328, Null}`, `{0.657, Null}`. So each function evaluation takes twice as long for the more complex function.

I also further narrowed it down: Everything is fast up to the integration.

I changed - as Edmund suggested in the comments - all definitions to `SetDelayed`, which did not improve the speed though.

Comment: All your _function_ definitions are using `Set` (`=`).  You should be using `SetDelayed` (`:=`).  For example `U[t_, freq_] := U0*Sin[2*\[Pi]*freq*t];`. Notice the colon `:=`.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, I changed it. Did not change the problem, though :-)

Comment: Another, most likely unrelated tip: do not use capital letters for defining your own symbols (a symbol can be anything, variables, constants, functions...). Capital letters are used by system functions and thus using them can result in unpredictable behavior from time to time.

Comment: Good point as well!

Comment: I'm not sure what "calculations" are being compared, esp. since the update indicates the calculations' timings are as expected, but you might try `NIntegrate` instead of `Integrate`.  Or check if the symbolic integral can be found with **exact** coefficients -- for example, `i0 = 1/10000` instead of `i0 = 0.0001`.  And **don't** use `SetDelayed` instead of `Set`, at least for the definitions involving `Integrate` in that case.

Comment: Now I'm confused about Set and SetDelayed, but that is something for tutorial instead of SE i guess. I will try your suggestions. I was comparing just the overall speed of the whole thing. Starting->Getting my result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of your problem is using `Integrate` with `i[t, freq]` in the expression.

It doesn't integrate.

Using `NIntegrate` (as suggested by Michael E2) the problem can be solved in a reasonable amount of time. Below are two changes.

```
ReI[freq_] := 
 2/tmax[freq]*NIntegrate[ReaF[t, freq], {t, 0, tmax[freq]}]
ImI[freq_] := 
 2/tmax[freq]*NIntegrate[ImaF[t, freq], {t, 0, tmax[freq]}]
```

I also modified the function definitions by replacing **=** (`Set`) with **:=** (`SetDelayed`).

I think you also should either give `Impe` the `Listable` attribute or use `Map` as shown below.

```
Results = Impe[#] & /@ Freqs

{332.822 - 0.00389736 I, 332.822 - 0.00490649 I, 
 332.822 - 0.0061769 I, 332.786 - 0.00777461 I, 
 332.822 - 0.00978973 I, 332.822 - 0.0123245 I, 332.822 - 0.0155157 I,
  332.822 - 0.0195331 I, 332.822 - 0.0245907 I, 332.822 - 0.0309578 I,
  332.822 - 0.0389736 I, 332.822 - 0.0490649 I, 332.786 - 0.0617559 I,
  332.822 - 0.0777626 I, 332.822 - 0.0978973 I, 332.822 - 0.123245 I, 
 332.822 - 0.155157 I, 332.822 - 0.195331 I, 332.821 - 0.245907 I, 
 332.821 - 0.309578 I, 332.821 - 0.389736 I, 332.821 - 0.490648 I, 
 332.821 - 0.617688 I, 332.82 - 0.777622 I, 332.819 - 0.978965 I, 
 332.818 - 1.23244 I, 332.816 - 1.55153 I, 332.813 - 1.95324 I, 
 332.808 - 2.45894 I, 332.8 - 3.09553 I, 332.787 - 3.89685 I, 
 332.766 - 4.90547 I, 332.734 - 6.17487 I, 332.683 - 7.77221 I, 
 332.602 - 9.78165 I, 332.474 - 12.3084 I, 332.271 - 15.4836 I, 
 331.95 - 19.4692 I, 331.443 - 24.4636 I, 330.646 - 30.7055 I, 
 329.394 - 38.474 I, 327.441 - 48.0797 I, 324.42 - 59.8389 I, 
 319.808 - 74.0175 I, 312.901 - 90.7301 I, 302.841 - 109.791 I, 
 288.734 - 130.543 I, 269.913 - 151.741 I, 246.3 - 171.642 I, 
 218.689 - 188.366 I, 188.743 - 200.469 I, 158.575 - 207.39 I, 
 130.158 - 209.537 I, 104.868 - 207.972 I, 83.3488 - 203.979 I, 
 65.645 - 198.712 I, 51.4232 - 193.038 I, 40.1789 - 187.519 I, 
 31.3747 - 182.47 I, 24.5166 - 178.029 I, 19.1847 - 174.226 I, 
 15.0388 - 171.028 I, 11.8104 - 168.374 I, 9.29146 - 166.193 I, 
 7.32143 - 164.412 I, 5.7772 - 162.966 I, 4.56416 - 161.797 I, 
 3.60948 - 160.855 I, 2.8569 - 160.097 I, 2.26279 - 159.489 I, 
 1.79325 - 159.001 I}
```

Then you can plot it

```
Res = Re[Results];
Ims = Im[Results];
marker = Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}];

ListPlot[Transpose[{Res, -Ims}], {Joined -> True, 
  PlotMarkers -> {marker, .03}, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Thick}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and make the table

```
TraditionalForm[TableForm[Transpose[{Freqs, Res, Ims}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That works very well. I tried it as well based on Michaels comment and it was indeed the bottleneck of the calculation. Very nice additions as well, I will check the attributes out as I don't know them yet.

Comment: @Jack LaVigne I pasted Jens code and followed your suggestions, `NIntegrate and Impe[#]&/@Freqs`. I get the error message: `NIntegrate::nlim: t = 2./freq is not a valid limit of integration` and after 6 minutes your result. The clue is not only NIntegrate, but mapping `Impe`. My question: Have you this error message too?

Comment: @Jack LaVigne to avoid this message I would recommend `ReI[freq_?NumericQ] :=` and `ImI[freq_?NumericQ] :=`

Comment: @Willinski Sorry, my mistake. I also copied Jens code but changed all the function definitions by replacing **=** (`Set`) with **:=** (`SetDelayed`). I neglected to indicate that in the answer. If you do that I think things should go smoothly.

Answer (score 4):

You can increase the performance of `i` considerably simply by making sure that `IBV` is evaluated only once.

```
i0 = 0.0001;
alpha = 0.5; 
E0 = 0; 
T = 293; 
z = 1; 
Cdl = 0.000001; 
iLimit = 0.0005;
U0 = 0.1;

bvVor = z*96485/8.314/T;

U[t_, freq_] := U0*Sin[2*π*freq*t]
DU[t_, freq_] := 2*freq*π*U0*Cos[2*freq*π*t]

iBV[t_, freq_] := 
  i0*(-Exp[(alpha - 1)*bvVor*(U[t, freq] - E0)] + 
     Exp[alpha*bvVor*(U[t, freq] - E0)]) + Cdl*DU[t, freq]

i[t_, freq_] :=
  Block[{ibv = iBV[t, freq]}, ibv*iLimit/(Abs[ibv] + iLimit)]

Timing[Do[iBV[0.1, 100], {10000}]][[1]]
```

> ```
> 0.207059
> ```

```
Timing[Do[i[0.1, 100], {10000}]][[1]]
```

> ```
> 0.239106
> ```

The same technique can be applied to improve overall performance.

```
iBV[t_, freq_] :=
  Block[{u, v},
    u = bvVor*U[t, freq] - E0;
    v = Exp[u alpha] (1 - Exp[-u]);
    i0 v + Cdl DU[t, freq]]
```

With this version of `iBV`, I get

```
Timing[Do[iBV[0.1, 100], {10000}]][[1]]
```

> ```
> 0.173164
> ```

and, of course, the performance of `i` improves, too.

```
Timing[Do[i[0.1, 100], {10000}]][[1]]
```

> ```
> 0.216504
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I did not know about the Block construct. I actually had the idea during my tests and implemented it using Module constructs, but I discarded it at some point. I found that the bottleneck was indeed in the Integrate step, as described just now in the answer by Jack LaVigne. Your answer is however very useful as well to further tweak the performance!

Comment: @m_goldgerg Nice improvement to the timing. Curious as to why you selected `Block` rather than `With`?

Comment: @JackLaVigne. `Block` is measurably faster than `With`.

Comment: @m_golderg Thanks for the tip. I was blissfully unaware.